# Is it possible to import some GML into Sql Server 2008?

Tags: file, sql-server-2008, import, gml-geographic-markup-lan

I have a GML file which i wish to import into Sql Server 2008.

Is this possible?

I know how to [read in some GML data if I hard-code the actual data](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2187/geography-markup-language-for-geospatial-data-in-sql-server/) .. but i'm not sure about getting it from a file.

Cheers!